# Cassandra python driver - how to re-insert a ResultSet

Tags: python, cassandra, resultset

I am using the python `cassandra-driver` to execute queries on a cassandra database and I am wondering how to re-insert a `ResultSet` returned from a `SELECT` query on table `A` to a table `B` knowing that `A` and `B` have the same columns but a different primary keys.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic, you'll need to:

1. create a prepare statement for INSERT ... INTO tableB ...
2. on each `ResultSet` from table `A`, extract the values and create a
   bound statement for table `B`, then execute the bound statement for
   insertion into `B`

You can use `asynchronous` queries to accelerate the migration a little bit but be careful to throttle the async.